# Breakpoint will not be hit - Typescript

Tags: typescript

When running the project I get the below error
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound"

need answer please

Comment: This is most likely related to the editor you use. TS will not do anything much with breakpoints. Depends on what tries to use them. We need more details where, when, and how you get this error.

Comment: Thanks for  your response I'm using visual studio and when run the project (multiple project) i get this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.